# JetBrains Rider hangs indefinitely when Creating solution file on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ide

JetBrains Rider hangs indefinitely when Creating solution file on Ubuntu 16.04. Already restarted both Rider and my system.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass this problem by choosing `ASP.NET Web Application` instead of `Empty Solution`.